# Xcode complains if I specify all constraints

Tags: autolayout, xcode9

In my UITableViewCell subclass I'm adding two elements, and I specify them as shown below.  Note how I'm leaving off the bottomConstraint on the ball.  When I do that, Xcode give a runtime warning saying height couldn't be determined and it's guessing for me.

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    contentView.addSubview(date)   // Date is a UILabel
    contentView.addSubview(balls)  // Balls is a UIStackView subclass

    balls.ballSize = 35  // This adds a height 35 constraint to balls

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        date.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        date.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
    ])

    regularConstraints = [
        date.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: balls.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        balls.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        //balls.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
        balls.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
}
```

So then I uncomment the line for the bottom anchor, which means I've now fully constrained the height of the cell.  But when I do that, I get all this garbage.  I have no idea why it's having an issue:

> (
>
> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002896f0 DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.width == 35   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000289880 DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.height == DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.width   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028aaf0 DidIWin.Balls:0x7f81c8d4fd70.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b1720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 10   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028ab40 DidIWin.Balls:0x7f81c8d4fd70.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b1720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom - 10   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028a190 'UISV-alignment' DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d500d0.bottom == DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.bottom   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028a370 'UISV-alignment' DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d500d0.top == DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.top   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000288390 'UISV-canvas-connection' DidIWin.Balls:0x7f81c8d4fd70.top == DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d500d0.top   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028a0a0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d500d0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':DidIWin.Balls:0x7f81c8d4fd70 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400028a2d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' DidIWin.FailureDetailCell:0x7f81ca0d5800'failure'.height == 44   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000289ce0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b1720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':DidIWin.FailureDetailCell:0x7f81ca0d5800'failure' )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000289c40 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6040001b1720'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':DidIWin.FailureDetailCell:0x7f81ca0d5800'failure' )>"
> ```
>
> )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000289880 DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.height == DidIWin.BallView:0x7f81c8d51af0.width   (active)>

The Balls stackview contains 6 BallView classes, and those have a height==width constraint on them.

Comment: Why do you pin constraints to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` within the `UITableViewCell`? You should ensure that the table view, not the cell, won't go beyond the safe area.  Try pin these constraints to the superview instead?

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski That's a very good question.  Habit I guess.  I switched to using the visual constraints and now it's working correctly.  I'm going to guess it did it the way you suggested.  Thanks.  I'll remember this for the future though.

Comment: I think it's prudent to disable this feature in .xibs which contain only custom controls. It's kind of a view controller responsibility to deal with them.